# ReliableItopic message Listener not working after Hazelcast split brain

Tags: hazelcast

Scenario: " 2 nodes hazelcast cluster" The `ReliableItopic` with topic name `sample_topic` is registered and messages were consumed in 2nd node. Node 1 publishes the message to the `ReliableItopic` with topic name `sample_topic`. The two nodes were up and messages were published and received.

After sometime the 2nd node got separated(member removed in hazelcast logs) and when joined(members joined and size was 2 )back, the `ReliableItopic` message listener stopped working and messages were not consumed.

Because of `Hazelcast` split brain ,facing this issue

hazelcast version:3.11.2

So whenever `Hazelcast` split brain Happens,we need to register the `ReliableItopic`message Listener?

Comment: I think I have a similar problem and I am able to reproduce it.
1. There are 3 members, A, B, C. A is the oldest.
2. All register reliable topic listeners.
3. Members A and B are terminated improperly.
4. Member C becomes a new master, but it will no longer receive any topic messages.
5. When members A and B restart, they receive messages.

Answer (score 0):

That’s not split brain, that’s a normal downscaling and then upscaling of cluster. Whatever events that were generated while the 2nd node was out, would not be delivered. If you are using the same configuration as before disconnection then as soon as the node comes back in, it should start normal operations.

Comment: During startup itself, Members split and join, After join the node 2 message listener not consuming any messages. This is not happening always. rarely it happens.cant able to reproduce. But happened nearly 4 times but coudn't find a solution .